# Focus event doesn't work by click on Imperavi wisywyg redactor inside ui-sortable table

Tags: javascript, yii2, jquery-ui-sortable, wysiwyg, redactor

I have ui-sortable table and Imperavi redactor inside it. 
All this based on yii2 framework.

And there is no ability to set cursor focus inside Imperavi redactor.
I find out following: if I delete inside `<div class="redactor-box">` (showed on screnshot) via chrome debug panel (circled with red color) three events `"click"`, `"mouseup"` and `"mousedown"` - focus works correct.

Any ideas, please, how to make focus inside redactor working using JS?

[image]

Imperavi redactor taken here: https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget

Sortable taken here: https://github.com/sjaakp/yii2-sortable-behavior

Piece of code inside view:

```
        <?= SortableGridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'orderUrl'     => ['order'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'table'],
        'columns'      => [
            [
                'label' => 'Type',
                'value' => 'template.type.name',
            ],
            [
                'label'  => 'Example',
                'value'  => function ($data) {
                    return \vova07\imperavi\Widget::widget([
                        'name' => 'redactor',
                        'settings' => [
                            'lang' => 'en',
                            'minHeight' => 200,
                            'plugins' => [
                                'clips',
                                'fullscreen',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'value' => $data->value
                    ]);
                },
                'format' => 'raw',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Edit',
                'value'  => function ($data) {
                    return '<div class="edit-table-sec"><a href="#"><i
                        class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>';
                    },
                'format' => 'raw',
            ]

        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: are you using `YiiBooster` for the `Redactor` .

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, no, I'm using yii2-imperavi-widget https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does "focus inside" mean?

Comment: @Ravenous it means when I'm clicking on the word "content" inside editor  (as it shown on screenshot) so cursor should appear there after that click and right in that place where click happened, but it doesn't. So actually I have no ability to edit content in redactor normally.

Comment: That's strange. Do you have a live version of this so I can debug too?

Comment: Can you try `'name' => 'redactor-' . $data->id`? There are multiple instances of it on the page and the name is not unique.

Comment: Thanx, I've changed 'name'. No, there is no live webpage for it.

Answer (score 1):

For those having the issue with [JQuery UI Sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), there are 2 ways to prevent it.

1. Disable the dragging on the Redactor input, by adding `.redactor_box` to the `cancel` selector of the plugin:

```js
$(list).sortable({
  cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,.redactor_box',
});
```

2. Only enable the dragging on a specific selector, like a panel heading for instance. You'd use the `handle` selector of the plugin:

```js
$(list).sortable({
  handle: '.panel-heading',
});
```